# My php program is not moving uploaded image on my raspberry pi directory

Tags: php, permissions, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Hi I'm having a hard time figuring out how to upload my image on my raspberry pi directory. I tried the code below but it returns a blank array. **/var/www/html/image**
Here's my code

HTML:

```
<form action="upload.php" class="dropzone text-center" id="left-drop"> </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/var/www/html/image/main";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "error\n";
}
?>
```

**My raspberry pi permissions:**

My folder permissions
[image]
Thank you.

Comment: who owns this directory? apache or root?

Comment: I set it to apache

Comment: Erm, your form doesn't have a file field?

Comment: Hi i used dropzoneJS which is a drag and drop to upload the image.

Answer (score 0):

I initially assumed that you knew the code you were writing allowed anyone to pwn your server, however you

- present your permissions in a screen shot of the LXDE file manager
- write code with no error checking or reporting
- provide no explanation what did happen and why it did not meet your expectations
- have not checked your log files for any errors
- did not provide a MCVE

makes me suspect this is not the case. (some hints above about how to start solving the problems)